# Sybase stored procedure insert limit with JDBC driver

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sqlanywhere

I'm having issues with stored procedures that have a lot of insert statements when using Sybase's jdbc driver. After 50-60 inserts, the stored procedure stops execution and returns. See code below.

I'm using Sybase Anywhere 10 and their jconn2.jar, but have also tried jconn3.jar.

java code:

```
String sp = "sp_test";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.execute(sp);
stmt.close();
```

stored procedure:

```
create procedure dba.sp_test()
as
begin
  declare @lnCount integer
  select @lnCount = 1
  while (@lnCount <= 1000 )
    begin
      insert into tableTest (pk) values (@lnCount)
      select @lnCount = @lnCount + 1
    end
end
```

After 58 inserts the procedure returns. Doing a select count(*) from tableTest afterward returns a count of 58. There are not SQLExceptions being thrown. I tried putting a begin/commit transaction around the insert, but it didn't make a difference. I've also tried the jodbc driver and it works fine, but I'm not able to use this as a solution because I've had other issues with it.

Comment: I can't check myself but try to put "set nocount on" into proc header.

Answer (score 0):

Using executeUpdate solved the problem:

```
String sp = "sp_test";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sp);
stmt.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you insert `con.commit()` immediately after `stmt.execute()` would work too.